# Grammatical function of "ever" in "His influence is greater than ever."

Tags: adverbs

What does the adverb *ever* in the sentence:

> His influence is greater than **ever**.

modify exactly?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, so I'm only leaving a comment for now, but this sentence could be considered an abridged version of: _His influence is greater than it ever has been_, or _His influence is greater than it's ever been before._ Maybe that helps?

Comment: It doesn't modify anything. It's function is that of **complement** of the preposition "than".

Comment: @BillJ I've actually never seen an adverb alone act as the object of a preposition. Perhaps this is specific to  *ever*, if one tries to substitute *ever* above with some other adverb (especially those ending with *ly*), it won't make much sense.

Comment: It's not common, perhaps, but they can, for example "it won't last [for long]"; I hadn't met her [till recently]".

Answer (score 1):

> His influence is greater.

[*Greater*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/greater) is an adjective.

> His influence is greater than ever.

[*Ever*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/ever) is modifying *greater*. (And *than ever* is an adverbial phrase.)

---

If you drop the use of *than*, and rephrase the sentence slightly, this will be even more apparent (even if it does subtly change the meaning of the sentence):

> His influence is *ever* greater.

Comment: But one, as **BillJ** pointed out, could also argue that *ever* acts as the object of the preposition *that* and the adverbial *than ever* plays, in turn, the role of a complement of the adjective *greater*.